# Webscraping from a variable

Tags: r, variables, web-scraping

I have a data.frame with two variables one of which contains only URLs.
I would like to use those URLs to scrape all of them and extracting relevant textual info from each and everyone of them and - by doing so - adding variables to the dataframe in order to have the textual analysis ready there.

```
FAO_CountryName     FAO_CountryURL
Algeria             http://www.fao.org/giews/countrybrief/country.jsp?code=DZA
Egypt               http://www.fao.org/giews/countrybrief/country.jsp?code=EGY
```

In other words, I would like to find a way to consider those URLs as proper html pages in a fashion that I could scrape them through the read_html() command.

The idea would be to have something like this at the end of the process:

```
    FAO_CountryName     FAO_CountryURL                                             FAOText
Algeria             http://www.fao.org/giews/countrybrief/country.jsp?code=DZA     Algeria is an interesting country
Egypt               http://www.fao.org/giews/countrybrief/country.jsp?code=EGY     Egypt is interesting as well but in a different way
```

Answer (score 0):

We first define  a function to harvest the info we want from a
specific URL:

```
library(rvest)
scrapeFAO <- function(x) {
    as.character(x) %>% 
        read_html() %>% 
        html_nodes('.Normal') %>% 
        .[1] %>% 
        html_text()
}

scrapeFAO("http://www.fao.org/giews/countrybrief/country.jsp?code=DZA")
# [1] "Reference Date: 24-November-2016"
```

This is just an example, we can actually harvest any element we need on that page. Pls read more about `rvest` package to expand the possibilities here.

Then we want to apply this function to each row and `cbind` the result to the initial `dataframe`:

```
final <- cbind(mydf, apply(mydf[2],1, scrapeFAO))
```

Note that there possibly are more efficient ways to do it.

Hope this helps

Comment: Pls consider accepting and upvoting the answer if you think it may help other people

Comment: I am new on stack, hence I haven't got reputation enough yet, apparently.
I will do as soon as >I get some more.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for the help. 

Ok for the script through which it is possible to consider the various URLs. Anyways, I do not get the way the formula should apply to each row and - in any case - it does not seem to work with my FAO_data  dataframe. 

Could you please clarify? Thanks again.

Comment: There was a typo, sry, try it now. If you want to understand what's going on try to run only `apply(mydf,1, scrapeFAO)`, and read about the `apply` function family.

Comment: This gives me an error

` Errore: '               Algeria             http://www.fao.org/giews/countrybrief/country.jsp?code=DZA' does not exist in current working directory ('/home/.../').
Called from: check_path(path)
Browse[1]> `

Comment: sorry, my bad, something went wrong copy-pasting, I edited the answer, should work now

Comment: Still not working. This is the error message I get:

> scrapeFAO("http://www.fao.org/giews/countrybrief/country.jsp?code=DZA")
Error in x$FAO_CountryURL : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: my apologies, I did last edit 'blind' now that i can test it re-edited. this is working on my side

Comment: Still does not working, sorry.
This is the message I get after the 'final' part:

Error during wrapup: '               Algeria             http://www.fao.org/giews/countrybrief/country.jsp?code=DZA' does not exist in current working directory ('/home/...').